# Angular, disable a button and then activate it using setTimeout in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to disable my button but then activate it a few seconds later. The code does run but the button is still disabled even after my code has executed.

```js
app.controller('spamController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


$scope.stopSpam = false;
  
function activateBtn(){
  $scope.stopSpam = false;
};


$scope.test = function(){
  
  $scope.stopSpam = true;
  activateBtn();

};

}]);
```

```html
<button ng-disabled="stopSpam" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="test()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$timeout` and call `activateBtn` after a few seconds:

```
app.controller('spamController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.stopSpam = false;

    function activateBtn(){
        $scope.stopSpam = false;
    };


    $scope.test = function(){
        $scope.stopSpam = true;
        $timeout(activateBtn, 3000);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: if I used plain javascript timeout instead of the $timeout why would it not work?

Comment: Because `setTimeout` doesnt trigger a `$digest` cycle - which is what updates the view.

Comment: Can call $scope.$apply() in setTimeout.

Comment: @dustmouse -- You can, but it's considered bad practice.